# Store all values (received by form) in database except 2 for modification in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel, i am trying to send all the values of a form to a database along with some other/modified values by using `fill()` in laravel 5.1.

here is how my controller looks like

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $pages = new Pages; //i have a model with name Pages
        $pages->fill(Input::all());
        $pages->save();
        return "data saved successfully";
    }
```

Whenever i want to fill data into the table i get these values.

[image]

But **before sending the data into database i want to mention some other attributes as well** like `$userid`, `change the datetime format to timestamp` and then i want to send the data to database.

I want to use `fill(Input::all());` method because if i need to add more field in the form, then i wont have to modify my controller or model.

Any suggestion will be helpful.Or any other best practice will also work. 
Thank you! (in advance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eloquent

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
   $request['user_id']='your id';
    Pages::create($request->all());
    return "data saved successfully";
}
```

If not eloquent
try this

```
    $pages = new Pages; //i have a model with name Pages
    $request['user_id']='your id';
    $pages->fill(Input::all());
    $pages->save();
    return "data saved successfully";
```